"I will collect my necklace after it is being prepared"
Could you please tell me?. Whether "After it is being prepared" mean "After it has been prepared" or "after its is prepared" or it could mean either/both.

prepared?  or repaired?

I think "prepare" will refer to "making of it" and "repaire"will refer to fixing the breakage" Please correct me if I am wrong.

No, "prepare" doesn't mean making of the necklace, it means getting the necklace ready for something.  "I prepared the necklace for repair by cleaning it." If you want to talk about it being made you might use "finished" or an adjective like "ready".

That's poor English. Where did that sentence come from?

It was self made by me.

The meaning is "when the preparation is completed", and so it is naturally expressed with a perfect aspect  "when/after it's been prepared".
Note that "prepared" is probably a mistake for "repaired".

Will "after+being+past participle always be "Has been+past paeticiple. Cannot "After+being+past participle be "is+past particple"?.eg: "Man dies after he is being shot in head"

Don't use present continous "is being shot"  You could use a participle  "being shot"

Ok thanks lastly but will "After is being shot"  be consider wrong?

"He is being shot" means that it is happening now. A newspaper headline could read Man dies after being shot in [the] head.

How about without "is" "He died after he being shot in the head" Will this be correct or wrong too? As i know we could say "He died after he got/was shot in head"

Yes thatt is wrong, but "He died after being shot in the head" is correct

Is being always implies either  “now, at the present” or “in the future.” An example of the former is I’m frustrated because I think I am being ignored. An example of the latter is My birthday is next Tuesday, and I am being taken out to lunch by my coworkers.

So if you really really want to use a present participle "My necklace will be collected by me after being prepared by you".  This sentence just proves that something can be grammatically correct but completely unidiomatic (and so "wrong")

When you want to express the idea that you will pick up the necklace when the work has been completed:

... after it has been prepared.

Use the past participle when "completion" is the idea. The present participle expresses  ongoing (not yet completed) action.
